# Convert SelectedObjectCollection to Collection of Specific Type

Tags: c#, winforms, collections, type-conversion

I have a WinForms multiselect listbox, and each item in the listbox is of type `MyClass`.

I am also writing a method that needs to take a parameter that is a collection of `MyClass`. It could be of type `MyClass[]`, `List<MyClass>`, `IList<MyClass>`, `IEnumerable<MyClass>`, etc. Any of those would work fine.

Somehow, I need to pass the selected items in the listbox to my method. But how would I convert `SelectedObjectCollection` to any of the `MyClass` collection types described above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> items = yourListBox.SelectedItems.Cast<MyClass>();
```

Answer (score 3):

One issue is that `ListBox` Items are not a generic list, so it could contain more than one type. If you call on `.AsQueryable` you are making the explicit cast on a non type-safe collection when you call on `.Select()`, Same goes with calling `.Cast<T>`, as you could get a cast exception. A safer approach would be to use `.OfType<T>()`

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> selected = listBox.SelectedItems.OfType<MyClass>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try Linq:

```
yourSelectedObjectCollection.AsQueryable().Select(o=>(MyClass)o).ToArray()
```

Comment: There is no `Select()` method after converting it to a Queryable object

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my TreeView, which contained 2 different classes.

```
if(SelectedItem is MyClass)
{
    MyClass passvariable = (MyClass)SelectedItem;
}
```

So if you select an item and the type of the item is MyClass, you create a new variable and set it with the SelectedItem as type MyClass.

You can do the same with a Collection, List, ...

```
if(MyList is ObservableCollection<MyClass>)
{
    ObservableCollection<MyClass> passlist = (ObservableCollection<MyClass>)MyList;
}
```

If you have more then 1 class in a ListBox, ComboBox, ... just check the SelectedItem with `if(... is type)`